# hosted CALayer in NSView bounds change

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have a custom CALayer hosted in an NSView, contained in an NSScrollView, setting properties on the CALayer will cause it's bounds to change.

The problem is that the NSView *really* wants to own the bounds of the contained CALayer, I can make it work by adding a KVO on the bounds so when the layer bounds changes it changes the NSView bounds (which changes the layer bounds to the same value - luckily KVO doesn't recurse if the value doesn't actually change).

Is there a better way? It would seem like going through the layout system would be better but then I can only specify my preferred frame (my bounds through my transform) - and this turns into setting my bounds, but with some amount of roundoff error.

How should a CALayer request a bounds change? Or is my current hack the preferred mechanism...

Answer (score 1):

I’m not totally sure what you’re doing, but I’d have the CALayer set an NSSize ivar on its NSView which changes the NSView’s intrinsic size for autolayout, and then call setNeedsRelayout:YES on the view. Don’t try to have the tail wag the dog if you’re going to use a layer attached to a view.